# Set the size of the boxes for Ipython wigets

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, widget

I'm woring on a simple interface where I have a text box and an interactive plot.
The idea of the text box in to used for some logs.

I'm able to get the plot and update the text from the same function, but my issue is that the text box is to large, I need to change its width.

Below is my current code and a screenshot of the result:

```
from IPython.display import display
from ipywidgets import Button, Layout, Textarea, HBox, VBox
import numpy as np 
from ipywidgets import interact, interactive, fixed, interact_manual
import plotly.graph_objects as go

def f(x):


    x = np.arange(x)
    t1.value = "".join([str(c) for c in x.tolist()] )  
    fig = go.Figure(data=go.Scatter(x=x, y=x**2))
    fig.show()

x = np.linspace(10,100,1)


interactive_plot = interactive(f, x=(1, 20))
l = Layout(flex='0 1 auto', height='400px', min_height='40px', width='10')
t1 = Textarea(value='TA: height=40px', layout=l)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The [layout attribute](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#The-layout-attribute) exposes CSS properties like `height`, `width`, `border`, `margin` of the ipywidgets. This allows one to control how the ipywidgets are laid out. It is possible to control the `width` and `height` of the textbox by tweaking the values in the `Layout` snippet below as required. The parameters accept values in pixels(px) or percentage of available space(%) or even `'auto'` to allow these values to be set automatically. You can find an example in the [docs](https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#Simple-examples). I've set the height as 30px and width as 'auto' to automatically set a width:

```
l = Layout(flex='0 1 auto', height='30px', min_height='40px', width='auto')
```

Output:

[image]